# Как получить значение свойства объекта?

Tags: java, ооп, объекты, методы, класс

Есть два класса, `Товары` и `Отделы (департамент)`, и их интерфейсы (свои сеттеры и геттеры). При добавлении товара сразу можно указать, к какому отделу он принадлежит.

При вызове `getDepartment()`, вместо конкретного значения получаю ссылку на него.

Как получить конкретное значение?

```
goods.getPrice() = 2000.12 
goods.getHasGuarantee() = false 
goods.getName() = Asus 
goods.getDepartment() = ru.javabegin.training.fastjava2.department.ElectronicDepartment@edf4efb 
goods.getCompany() = AsusLtd.
```

Answer (score 1):

Если значение свойства объекта является объектом, то для получения свойства объекта нужно указать какое свойство требуется получить и воспользоваться методом, который возвращает это свойство.

```
goods.getDepartment().getName()
```

Comment: выдает null значение

Comment: А я  указывал конкретное значение

Comment: Спасибо! Да, Вы точно указали,что свойство объекта является объектом, как указать свойство?

Comment: Обычно свойство объекта недоступно за пределами класса, поэтому можно использовать геттер.